# Scale factors in orthogonal coordinate systems

Tags: differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, curvilinear-coordinates

I'm trying to reduce the general tensor expression for either orthogonal or non orthogonal 
$$\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{V} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{g}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(\sqrt{g}V^i \right)$$ where $V^i$ are the contravarant components of V.

to be for orthogonal using

$$g_{ij}=h^2_i~,~i=j$$
$$g=h_1^2h_2^2h_3^2$$

So I use $$V^i=g^{ij}V_j$$

and get

$$\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{V} = \frac{1}{h_1h_2h_3}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(h_1h_2h_3g^{ij}V_j \right)=\frac{1}{h_1h_2h_3}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(h_1h_2h_3\frac{V_i}{h_i^2} \right)$$

which has an extra factor of $\frac{1}{h_i}$ from the answer

$$\frac{1}{h_1h_2h_3}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\left(h_2h_3 V_1 \right)+\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}\left(h_1h_3 V_2 \right)+\frac{\partial}{\partial x_3}\left(h_1h_2 V_3 \right) \right)$$

I have absolutely no idea what I'm missing here. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your calculation is correct. The issue here is that the components $V_i$ in the answer is not exactly $g_{ij}V^j$, but $V_i = V^i h_i$ (no summation). By relation $V = V^i e_i = V^i h_i \frac{e_i}{h_i} = (V^i h_i) \hat{e_i}$. So $V_i := V^ih_i$.  Look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2172822/divergence-in-curvilinear-coordinates) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_coordinates)

Comment: hmm I'm not sure I'm getting it from either link. The book I'm using (Boas) has defined $V^i=g^{ij}V_j $ what is different between $V^i=g^{ij}V_j $ and $V^i=V_ih^i$?

Comment: In Boas, the derivation of above formula using convention $V = V_ie_i$, where $\{e_i\}$ is an $\textbf{orthonormal}$ basis.

Comment: oh so my problem is that my basis isn't orthonormal?

Comment: Yes. The notation in your first eq. is for general basis